# Mootools : I want to traverse following array in mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, associative-array

I am learning mootools. I have an array in following format.
I want to traverse it in for loop but dont know how to do it.

```
{'apple' : { 'prize' : 10 , 'color' : 'Red' } ,
'banana' : { 'color' : 'red', 'prize' : 20, 'quantity' : 12 } }
```

I am getting above structure of array from another module thats why i cant change its structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are objects, not arrays.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/AkVvY/

```
var obj = {'apple' : { 'prize' : 10 , 'color' : 'Red' } ,
'banana' : { 'color' : 'red', 'prize' : 20, 'quantity' : 12 } };

for( var name in obj ) {
    alert( name + ': ' + obj[name].color );
}
```

You don't need a library for this.

If you're concerned that there may be additions to `Object.prototype`, then do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/AkVvY/1/

```
for( var name in obj ) {
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty( name ) ) {
        alert( name + ': ' + obj[name].color );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MooTools has a function for this as well, so you don't need to use the `hasOwnProperty` check yourself:

```
Object.each({ 'prize' : 10 , 'color' : 'Red' }, function(value, key){
    // what you like to do.
});
```

See the documentation: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Object#Object:Object-each

It is indeed important to know the difference between an array and object. The above example uses an Object literal.

For arrays you could use Array:each.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each(function(value, key){
    // what you like to do.
});
```

Docs: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Array#Array:each

But as mentioned in the other answer, you could do this with `for (var key in obj){}` loops for objects, and `for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++){}`loops for arrays in plain JavaScript

Comment: I tried to use this code with my structure but cant get any results : Object.each({ 'prize' : 10 , 'color' : 'Red' }, function(value, key){
    // what you like to do.
});

Comment: +1 @arian. @Johny: you are probably using an old version of mootools then. try `obj.each(function(el) { console.log(el); });`